# Excluding laser beams, what is the first instance of an idea from military science fiction that became a military fact?

Tags: military-sf

In 1898's "War of the Worlds", heat rays(lasers?) were science fiction. Now military lasers are science facts. Is there a science fiction idea that turned into an actual military weapon/vehicle invention before lasers were created? I'm intersted in the earliest work of military science fiction that depicted a non-exsistant military weapon/vehicle that came to exist as an actual military weapon/vehicle, and what is the weapon/vehicle?

```
No. The drawings of Leonardo Da Vinci don't count.
```

I'm looking for a military scifi story, the idea that it introduced, and the actual real world device that completes the circle.

Comment: Interesting question. Do you want to limit it to written fiction? Because otherwise, you could essentially say that, for example, even the "inventor" of simple stone tools had a (science) fiction first and then realized it as some kind of possible weapon.

Comment: Does Arthur Clarke's ""World without wires" where he described commsats count?

Comment: Out of curiosity; which one of the propositions in my answer did you find most helpful? I could highlight it for future reference.

Comment: @bitmask It was your angle on the submarine technology he envisioned. Yes. Subs were around, but the abilities he envisioned were not.

Comment: @MajorStackings: Interesting, I found the space ships more convincing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**tl;dr** The accepted portion of this answer is Jules Verne's interpretation of submarine ships that were dramatically superior than the very first actual submarines that emerged during his time (no pun intended ... well, maybe a bit).

---

The answer is twofold, because the further you go back in time, the more watery the term "science fiction" gets. So the first part is the younger one, which is stricter regarding the term:

### Jules Verne (1870)

Although technically the very first sub-marines are significantly older than Verne himself, he "*wrote about space, air, and underwater travels before air travel and practical submarines were invented*".<sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Verne)</sup> So the tactical use of large submarines capable of carrying many dozen of hands for war was not possible at the time [Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Thousand_Leagues_Under_the_Sea) was written. Although to be fair, the very first military submarine -- [The Plongeur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_submarine_Plongeur) -- was launched 7 years prior to the release of the book. Compared to modern submarines this seems like a mere toy ship, especially looking at the propulsion capabilities. So the features of the Nautilus still seem to be a work of science fiction to me.

Besides the submarine, I would also count the **space vehicles** envisioned by Verne that were definitely not possible in his era, but later served as ["weapons" in the **cold war**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Race). Although, fortunately, exploring the space has brought nations together in collaboration today (well, except [Dmitry Rogozin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitry_Rogozin), he's got it all wrong) -- technically, they started off as a (cold-)war machine. So this most likely answers your question best.

### Homer (-850)

The [Iliad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad) by Homer could be interpreted as a work of fiction, although again, the concept of science fiction as we use it today would be a bit of a stretch. However,

> [..] the warfare shown in the Iliad, and the way in which it was depicted, **had a profound and very traceable effect on Greek warfare** in general. In particular, the effect of epic literature can be broken down into three categories: tactics, ideology, and the mindset of commanders <sup>[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad#Influence_on_classical_Greek_warfare)</sup>

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

If you want to go even further you could even take the [Trojan Horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Horse#Factual_explanations) as an example. Although it is not mentioned in the Iliad itself (but in even older texts) Homer alluded to it in the [Odyssey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey). It appears to be disputed how literally true the legend of the "Wooden Horse" actually is, but it most certainly was not an actual Horse-like structure. You could argue that the tactic depicted in this tale was later turned into an actual war tactic, although not as an actual horse, but rather a proverbial Trojan Horse.

Comment: The CSA in the American Civil war built the Hundley, which attacked and sank a US Warship before sinking itself on the return.  So the Nautilus was  an extrapolation of existing technology.

Answer (score 10):

The first one involving technology would be... surprise, H.G. Wells (*The Land Ironclads*, a 1903 short story).

He took Diplock's idea of a pedrail locomotion and applied it to all-terrain armored military vehicles.

Lo and behold, The Royal Navy and the Landships Committee (wonder where they got that name eh?) at Churchill's urging experimented with the idea of armoured tractors, some using pedrails... when that failed, they switched to caterpillar tracks, which became the basis of all tank design.

---

The first one NOT involving technology that I'm aware of would be Heinlein's *Starship Troopers* (1959).

- Powered armor exoskeletons ([real attempt](http://web.archive.org/web/20060116201552/http://www.sciencenews.org/articles/20010630/bob8.asp)).
- Volunteer non-conscript military (admittedly, there's no evidence that the real life idea originated with RAH, but he definitely helped popularize it)
- Concept of space "airborne" infantry

---

Another possibility is orbital kinetic bombardment.

The original (using planetary bodies) was E.E. "Doc" Smith's Lensman series; and [real-life military idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_bombardment#Project_Thor) was proposed by non other than future SciFi author Jerry Pournelle:

> Project Thor is an idea for a weapons system that launches kinetic projectiles from Earth orbit to damage targets on the ground. Jerry Pournelle originated the concept while working in operations research at Boeing in the 1950s before becoming a science-fiction writer.

---

Also, Jules Verne (e.g. Scuba gear and ballistic sub propulsion from *20,000 leagues*)

Comment: Interestingly enough, one of the most likely concepts (rail gun) that is always described as "scifi" did NOT actually, to the best of my knowledge, originate in SciFi work, but as a patent filed in 1919.

Comment: It's worth noting that Starship Troopers is now required reading for at least some branches of the US military.

Comment: As for volunteer military, Karl May already describes indian tribes using such.  Of course, the carrier choices are a bit limited, and any profession other than fighter either takes only very few boys or likely comes with low social status and no chance of wealth, so boys are quite motivated to become fighters, and they also can't quit once they chose that path, but technically it's still volunteer military.

Comment: Scuba diving already sort of existed in Verne's time, and indeed, Verne's *Eight Hundred Leagues on the Amazon*, which is a more realistic novel, features such a diver.  His diving suite is bulky, and air is pumped in through a long pipe from a boat above the diver, and it's quite expensive, but it's still scuba diving, right?

Comment: SCUBA is an acronym -- Self Contained Underwater Breathing Apparatus. A Diving Bell is not really Self Contained.

Answer (score 4):

JONATHAN SWIFT (1710)

If we classify Jonathan Swift's Gullivers Travels as science fiction, then the floating city of Laputa comes to mind.   As an imaginary floating platform, Laputa's custom of throwing rocks and/or othe incindearies (e.g. flaming oil as early napalm?) during military conflicts down at rebellious cities on the ground seems the first time that aerial bombardment from an artificial structure (as opposed so simply birds or other flying creatures dropping things) was conceived as a method of warfare.   This would have been in ~1710.

To the case that Laputa was a science fiction story vs. simply a fantasy is that the explanation relied on a "scientific" basis rather than simply magic.  Specifically,per Wiki, Laputa was described as a flying island or rock, about 4.5 miles in diameter, with an adamantine base, which its inhabitants can maneuver in any direction using magnetic levitation.Its inhabitants were devoted to reason, science and mathematics, not magic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laputa

Answer (score 2):

Missed Verne by only 2 years, but I think it is worth of mentioning, because it involves technologies which were not existing at all in that time (submarines existed before 1870, but they were not efficient enough to have a significant effect).

### Jókai Mór: The Novel of Next Century (1872)

This novel features the development of aviation and its adaption to warfare. This adaption is similar as that of the real world, at the beginning they were not fitted with weapons and had to improvise, but later aircraft specifically designed for combat emerged. It also features some kind of armored land vehicles in the role of modern tanks. It can be considered as science fiction, as the presentation of the development of (then) futuristic technology plays a central role in the story.